# “Launch Classic Notebook” option is gone from the JupyterLab Help menu

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

The deprecation of Notebook in favor of Lab is going on and since JupyterLab 4.0.0 the dependency on Notebook and with it also the useful backward compatibility option “Launch Classic Notebook” was removed from JupyterLab Help menu. Any workarounds?

Comment: Did you try installing `nbclassic`?

Comment: Yes, but not directly - it got installed as a dependency of `notebook` (and also - indirectly - as a secondary and tertiary dependency of `jupyter-contrib-nbextensions` and `jupyter-nbextensions-configurator`)

Answer (score 4):

Apparently this useful trick still works:

-> **manually changing the base URL to `/tree`:**

- Before 4.0.0:
  `<JUPYTER_URL>/lab` -> `<JUPYTER_URL>/tree`
- Since 4.0.0:
  `<JUPYTER_URL>/` -> `<JUPYTER_URL>/tree`

---

Note: if it doesn't work, check if you have Jupyter Notebook installed (e.g. `$ pip show notebook`), and if not - install it (separately from `jupyterlab`), [here's how](https://docs.jupyter.org/en/latest/install.html).